# Display text fields at center of the page

Tags: html, css

We have form page like [this](http://stylebaby.com/sendfriend/product/send/id/18412/cat_id/1107/):

[image]

We wanted to make design like [this](http://stylebaby.com/contact-us):

[image]

Means:

1. Name & email and their text field should display as like above image.
2. Message & its box should display like comment section.
3. Same result need for Name & email present below.
4. Need space between 2 button present in bottom.

**css**

```css
media only screen and (min-width: 1224px)
.send-friend h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1224px)
  form .legend {
    border: none;
    color: #000;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.4;
    margin: 0 0 15px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    text-rendering: optimizespeed;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
}
```

**html**

```html
<div class="send-friend">
  <?php
echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml();
?>
  <div class="page-title">
    <h1><?php
echo $this->__('Email to a Friend');
?></h1>
  </div>
  <form action="<?php
echo $this->getSendUrl();
?>" method="post" id="product_sendtofriend_form">
    <div class="fieldset">
      <?php
echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey');
?>
      <h2 class="legend"><?php
echo $this->__('Sender Details');
?></h2>
      <ul class="form-list" id="sender_options">
        <li class="fields">
          <div class="field">
            <label for="sender_name" class="required"><em>*</em><?php
echo $this->__('Name:');
?></label>
            <div class="input-box">
              <input name="sender[name]" value="<?php
echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getUserName());
?>" title="<?php
echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('Name'));
?>" id="sender_name" type="text" class="input-text required-entry" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="field">
            <label for="sender_email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php
echo $this->__('Email:');
?></label>
            <div class="input-box">
              <input name="sender[email]" value="<?php
echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getEmail());
?>" title="<?php
echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('Email Address'));
?>" id="sender_email" type="email" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="wide">
          <label for="sender_message" class="required"><em>*</em><?php
echo $this->__('Message:');
?></label>
          <div class="input-box">
            <textarea name="sender[message]" class="input-text required-entry" id="sender_message" cols="3" rows="3"><?php
echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getMessage());
?></textarea>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="fieldset">
      <h2 class="legend"><?php
echo $this->__('Recipient Details');
?></h2>
      <ul class="form-list" id="recipients_options">
        <li class="fields">
          <div class="field">
            <label for="recipients_name" class="required"><em>*</em><?php
echo $this->__('Name:');
?></label>
            <div class="input-box">
              <input name="recipients[name][]" type="text" class="input-text required-entry" id="recipients_name" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="field">
            <label for="recipients_email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php
echo $this->__('Email Address:');
?></label>
            <div class="input-box">
              <input name="recipients[email][]" value="" title="<?php
echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('Email Address'));
?>" id="recipients_email" type="email" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons-set">
      <p class="back-link"><a href="#" onclick="history.back(); return false;"><small>&laquo; </small><?php
echo $this->__('Back');
?></a></p>
      <button type="submit" class="button<?php
if (!$this->canSend()):
?> disabled<?php
endif;
?>"<?php
if (!$this->canSend()):
?> disabled="disabled"<?php
endif;
?>><span><span><?php
echo $this->__('Send Email');
?></span></span></button>
    <div id="max_recipient_message" style="display:none;">
      <?php
if ($this->getMaxRecipients()):
?>
      <p class="limit"><?php
    echo $this->__('Maximum %d email addresses allowed.', $this->getMaxRecipients());
?></p>
      <?php
endif;
?>
    </div>
    <?php
if (1 < $this->getMaxRecipients()):
?>
    <p id="add_recipient_button">
      <button type="button" onclick="add_recipient();" class="button"><span><span><?php
    echo $this->__('Add Recipient');
?></span></span></button>
    </p>
    <?php
endif;
?>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You probably need to add a `max-width` to all your fields. Or maybe simply a `width`. Please post your HTML

Comment: On the contact page you posted, the form has the following CSS `#contactForm {
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    width: 75%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}` - note the `width: 75%` - I guess you're missing that

Comment: @CalvT updated the html

Comment: @nsdlfefinedieicbe sorry to say but you should hire developer and he will fix all your issue(fast) rather then asking for each and every point. Sorry for my words but m seeing you with this site from so many days so said. Please don't take in other way. Thank you.

Comment: @Leothelion  as i am new to css, i am learning css. thanks for your suggestions & support. i will consider your words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try to put the form in a `<div>` and then increase the width of the input boxes.

Do put padding to leave some white space for aesthetic purpose :)

Example `<input type="text" id="text" name="text_name" style="width: 300px;" />`
(if you are not considering responsiveness)

I would prefer if you use `.text{max-width:110%;}`

Since you are new to CSS, the previous CSS shown can be used for multiple ids by putting a comma and the respective tags you would like the following css to apply.

Then for the words indicating which textbox is what, you could use a `text-align:left`

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap class `text-center` to set alignment in center position.

Comment: Did he mention using Bootstrap? Seems like a pretty heavy library to load just to accomplish `text-align: center` behavior.